# Timezone conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the following query to gather data for the month of May 2015. The column `created` is a `datetime` column which is in `UTC`, I would like to convert it to `PST`. Therefore, I'm using the `DATEADD()` function.

```
( select count(ordernumber) as Orders , 
         sum(revenue)       as Revenue, 
         'Type1'            as OrderType,
         CAST( CAST( DATEPART(Month, DATEADD(hh,-7,created)) as varchar )
             + '/' + '1/'
             + CAST( DATEPART(Year, DATEADD(hh,-7,created))  as varchar)
             as Date ) as Date
  from ORDERS
  where orange = 1
    and custnum = '1234'
    and DATEADD(hh,-7,DATEADD(hh,-7,created)) between
              CAST('2015-05-01 00:00:00.000' as DateTime)
          and CAST('2015-05-31 23:59:59.999' as DateTime)
  group by CAST( CAST( DATEPART(Month, DATEADD(hh,-7,created)) as varchar )
               + '/' + '1/'
               + CAST( DATEPART(Year, DATEADD(hh,-7,created))  as varchar )
               as Date )
)
```

Here's the output of this query:

```
Orders    Revenue    OrderType    Date
139 1383.05 Type1   2015-05-01
3   29.85   Type1   2015-06-01
```

As we can see above, I'm getting the data for part of June as well, which I don't want. I only want the correct data from May 2015. How do I do that? Am I missing something in the conversion?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please see [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
CAST('2015-05-31 23:59:59.999' as DateTime)
```

is coming out to `2016-06-01` because the precision of the `DateTime` type is [3.33 ms](http://www.sqlphilosopher.com/wp/2012/10/precision-in-datetime-data-types/). Instead of using `BETWEEN`, use an expression that's closed on one side and open on the other, like:

```
x >= '2015-05-01' and x < '2015-06-01'
```

**Edit:** You're also using this in your `WHERE` clause:

```
DATEADD(hh,-7,DATEADD(hh,-7,created))
```

So the date you're using to filter your result set has 14 hours subtracted from it rather than 7, whereas the date you're displaying in the result set is the stored date minus 7 hours, which explains why they're sometimes different dates.

Comment: Noted. When I try to `select CAST('2015-05-31 23:59:58.999' as DateTime)`, I get the correct date, which is `2015-05-31 23:59:59.000`. But when I change the `where` clause in my query to `between CAST('2015-05-01 00:00:00.000' as DateTime) and CAST('2015-05-31 23:59:50.999' as DateTime)` (note that the end date has `50` seconds and not `59` seconds), I still get part of June's data. Why is that?

Comment: @Patthebug, please see my edit for something I missed the first time around.

Comment: Ahh, that was pure oversight on my end. Your solution works well, thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

Your between clause (as noted) is incorrect, but your code is...more verbose than it needs to be. You might find something like the following to be more expressive and easier to understand. Here we use a [*Common Table Expression (CTE)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.110).aspx) to create what is essentially a virtual view, containing the additional column we need: a representation of the month that the order was created. We'll use the convention that that is a `date` value with the day being the 1st of the month. Once we have that, it's easy:

```
declare @UTC_offset   int  = -8 -- PST is UTC-08:00, PDT is UTC-07:00
declare @report_month date = '2015-05-01' ,

with
(
  select * ,
         month_created_pst = dateadd(day,
                               1-day( convert(date , dateadd(hour , @UTC_offset,created ) ) ) ,
                               dateadd(hour , @UTF_offset , created ) 
                             )
  from ORDERS
) as orders_local_time
select Orders    = count( t.ordernumber ) ,
       Revenue   = sum(   t.revenue     ) ,
       OrderType = 'Type1'              ,
       Date      = t.month_created_pst
from ORDERS t
where t.orange            =  1
  and t.custnum           =  '1234'
  and t.date_created_pst  >= @report_month
  and t.month_created_pst =  @report_month
group by t.month_created_pst
```